# how do I use Repl.it in my web application?

Tags: python, web, read-eval-print-loop

I am a novice programmer trying to make a site like codecademy labs. So I figured that codecademy uses jsrepl for their code execution. But I am having problems to embed in my website. Also I only want python as my language. So how do I configure the source to meet my requirements?

Comment: see documentation https://github.com/replit/jsrepl - we can't help you more without your code.

Comment: how to I configure the source to include only python?

Answer (score 2):

You can use repl.it's API which makes it really easy to build this sort of sites: https://repl.it/api